# Cannot access web service in iOS

Tags: web-services, ios6, info-plist

I want to connect with a web service from my iOS app. Previously my URL was `http://<domain name>/mobilews/mobilews.asmx`. Recently I changed to `http://<domain name>/mobilewstest/mobilews.asmx`

I have put my URL in info plist file. But after I changed this into new URL I cannot login to that.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",serverURL,[queryString  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]; 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSHTTPURLResponse *response ;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

int statusCode = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];`
```

Here `returnData` become `nill` and `statusCode` is 0. But this `urlString` is successfully logged in to the web service when it gives in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL HERE"];
    NSError *connectionError = nil;
    NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&connectionError];
    NSInteger code = [connectionError code];
    if (code != 0)
    {
        NSString *locDesc = [NSString stringWithString:[connectionError localizedDescription]];
        NSString *locFail = [NSString stringWithString:[connectionError localizedFailureReason]];
        NSLog(@"Error: %d %@ %@", code, locDesc, locFail);
    }
    else if ([inData length] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No data");
    }
    else{
    NSData *resultData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```

I see you send a syncronous request... try this its more an easy approach.

Comment: but then responseString is empty.Why is that?

Comment: try it with a hardcoded url and see again... and try the same hardcoded url in browser.

Comment: Just make sure, the method type is "GET" not "POST"

Comment: thank u so much,, When I hard coded its working .But I want to get the status code to check whether it is 200 or not. How can I chek this according to ur code

Comment: Hi but I want to know why it works when it hardcode. "NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",serverURL,[queryString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];" if I put this string it not works . why is that?

Comment: apply the pecentescapes on the whole urlstring and use NSLog to check if the url is correct.